HCSR04 Ultrasonice sensor in ESP32 - giving wrong values
I am trying to test the ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04) using a ESP32 development board. The code I used is this:
#define TRIG_PIN 34  // Arduino pin connected to TRIG pin of HC-SR04
#define ECHO_PIN 35 // Arduino pin connected to ECHO pin of HC-SR04

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Start the Serial communication
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT); // Set TRIG_PIN as output
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);  // Set ECHO_PIN as input
}

void loop() {
  // Clear the TRIG_PIN
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Trigger the sensor by setting TRIG_PIN high for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);

  // Read the echo pin, and calculate the distance
  // long duration = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);

  // Read the echo pin with a timeout of 25,000 microseconds (25 milliseconds)
  long duration = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH, 25000);

  Serial.print("Dur = ");
  Serial.println(duration);

  // Calculate the distance in centimeters
  float distanceCm = (duration / 2.0) * 0.0343;

  // Print the distance to the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distanceCm);
  Serial.println(" cm");

  delay(1000);  // Wait for a second before the next measurement
}

I have connected the Trig pin of sensor to D5 (34) pin in board. And the Echo pin of sensor to the D18 (35).
And the VCC of sensor to the Vin of ESP32 board. Right now, there is no external power source. The board is connected via USB.
The problem is, I am receiving values in the serial monitor like this:
Distance: 164.88 cm
Dur = 1
Distance: 0.02 cm
Dur = 9613
Distance: 164.86 cm
Dur = 1
Distance: 0.02 cm
Dur = 9605
Distance: 164.73 cm
Dur = 9579
Distance: 164.28 cm
Dur = 1
Distance: 0.02 cm
Dur = 9603
Distance: 164.69 cm
Dur = 9610
Distance: 164.81 cm
Dur = 9579
Distance: 164.28 cm
Dur = 2
Distance: 0.03 cm
Dur = 2
Distance: 0.03 cm
Dur = 1
Distance: 0.02 cm
Dur = 9599
Distance: 164.62 cm
Dur = 9579
Distance: 164.28 cm

These values are received when I keep my hand very close to the sensor. And even when I remove my hand, similar values are shown. It looks like the distance calculation is wrong. So I tried testing the value returned by the echo. That's what the "Dur = " values are.
What could be the reason? I tried testing with other sensors (I had 4 of them). All are working like this.
Btw, am a newbie. Is there something I missed?

There is a necessary blanking period because the outgoing pulse is immediately sensed. (I've not looked at your code.) You may need to ignore returns that occur early. Are you aware and taking that into account? I recall seeing some doc on that a couple of years ago.

@periblepsis I am using a 10 microseconds delay between HIGH and LOW for the TRIG_PIN. Is that ok or needs to be changed? If so, is there a standard value? Or I should do by trial and error?

The docs I saw gave a specific time, worst case. It's possible you need to ignore things for longer than that. What's the doc say? (I used a couple of these, together with a separate radar system and have had no problems once I worked out the delay. But it has been a while now.)

@periblepsis The online datasheet I saw also says 10us. That's what I used in code.

Try making it longer then. You need to get rid of those fast return values. Could be as simple as that. Worth a try. It would be what I'd try with numbers like that coming through. I might also try buying from a more reputable supplier, it I'd bought cheaply at first, too. Experiment.

@periblepsis thanks I am testing by changing the values. Also raising a ticket with the supplier

Truly, best wishes. I bought a bunch for my project years ago. A safety system for the kitchen stove to make sure that if the kitchen was left vacant for more that a couple of minutes, that the stove circuit would shut down. Everything is working fine and is still in use. This is because my daughter is profoundly autistic and it isn't safe to leave an active stove. A code must be entered to enable the stove and an active presence is always required to sustain the active stove in order to protect her.

Implement the additional delay between digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW) and pulseIn() to ignore early trigger. This is different from the pulse width created by delayMicroseconds(10).

@periblepsis That's a nice idea you implemented. Glad to hear that you created that project for the safety of your kid! :)

@Jens thanks. I will try adding some delays and see how it comes through.

@Jens I tried added some delay in between, but doesn't seem to work properly. I will try some more adjustments in the delay with trial and error method.

The HC-SR04 needs a supply of 5 V, the ESP32 runs on 3.3 V. What kind of level shift do you use?

@Jens I connected the Vcc of sensor to the Vin of ESP32 and am powering the board via the USB port (while development).

So you need a level shifter to make the 0/3.3 V signals from ESP32 I/O compatible to the 0/5 V signal levels of the sensor. A voltage divider 2.2 kohm / 3.3 kohm in the echo signal path probably will work here. But also try to use other I/O pins because GPIO34-GPIO39 are input only. I assume there is no trigger signal at GPIO34. Can you ckeck this with a scope?

@Jens thanks! I got reply from the supplier saying that the pins could be connected wrong and he asks me to connect to D5 & D18 by defining the pin numbers as #define TRIG_PIN 5  #define ECHO_PIN 18 and that worked! I was referring this diagram for identifying the pins: https://circuits4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/ESP32-Pinout.jpg and I interpreted the diagram wrongly!

If the issue is solved, rather than changing the title, you can write your own answer and accept it so that the system will mark it as resolved.

@winny done! Thanks.

My supplier responded to my ticket saying that the pins defined in code might be wrong. So, it should be like this:
#define TRIG_PIN 5  // pin connected to TRIG pin of HC-SR04
#define ECHO_PIN 18  // pin connected to ECHO pin of HC-SR04

And that worked! I was referring this diagram for the pins, but it looks like I interpreted it wrongly :

So basically, when we connect to the D5 & D18 in the board, we are supposed to define the pin numbers in code as 5 & 18. As per the diagram, I thought it should be 34 & 35.
Thank you @periblepsis and @Jens for giving me suggestions and pointers in the comments section. Highly appreciate that!
